# Getting BadSqlGrammarException in spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-jdbc

I have recently tried to update spring boot version from 2.3.3.RELEASE to 2.6.7.

with this version change I  had modified syntax for initialize-schema in application.yml as below.
Old code

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: local
  batch:
    initialize-schema: never
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
  main:
    web-application-type: none
```

New code

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: local
  batch:
    jdbc:
      initialize-schema: never
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
  main:
    web-application-type: none
```

With this change I had also modified in-memory Map-based job repository DefaultBatchConfigurer class from use of MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean to JobRepositoryFactoryBean.
(As MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean is deprecated.)

Old DefaultBatchConfigurer code

```
  @Bean
  DefaultBatchConfigurer batchConfigurer() {
    return new DefaultBatchConfigurer() {
      private final JobRepository jobRepository;
      private final JobExplorer jobExplorer;
      private final JobLauncher jobLauncher;

      {
        MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean jobRepositoryFactory = new MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean();
        try {
          this.jobRepository = jobRepositoryFactory.getObject();
          MapJobExplorerFactoryBean jobExplorerFactory = new MapJobExplorerFactoryBean(
              jobRepositoryFactory);
          this.jobExplorer = jobExplorerFactory.getObject();
          SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
          assert jobRepository != null;
          jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
          jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
          this.jobLauncher = jobLauncher;
        } catch (Exception e) {
          throw new BatchConfigurationException(e);
        }
      }

      @Override
      public JobRepository getJobRepository() {
        return jobRepository;
      }

      @Override
      public JobExplorer getJobExplorer() {
        return jobExplorer;
      }

      @Override
      public JobLauncher getJobLauncher() {
        return jobLauncher;
      }
    };
  }
```

Modified code is as below.

```
  @Bean
  DefaultBatchConfigurer batchConfigurer(DataSource dataSource, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
    return new DefaultBatchConfigurer() {
      private final JobRepository jobRepository;
      private final JobExplorer jobExplorer;
      private final JobLauncher jobLauncher;
      {
        try {
          // job repository
          JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
          factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
          factory.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
          factory.afterPropertiesSet();
          this.jobRepository = factory.getObject();

          // job launcher
          SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
          assert jobRepository != null;
          jobLauncher.setJobRepository(this.jobRepository);
          jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
          this.jobLauncher = jobLauncher;

          // job explorer
          JobExplorerFactoryBean jobExplorerFactoryBean = new JobExplorerFactoryBean();
          jobExplorerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
          jobExplorerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
          this.jobExplorer = jobExplorerFactoryBean.getObject();
        } catch (Exception e) {
          throw new BatchConfigurationException(e);
        }
      }

      @Override
      public JobRepository getJobRepository() {
        return jobRepository;
      }

      @Override
      public JobExplorer getJobExplorer() {
        return jobExplorer;
      }

      @Override
      public JobLauncher getJobLauncher() {
        return jobLauncher;
      }
    };
  }
```

After this change I am getting BadSqlGrammarException.

```
10:26:33.528 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - After shutdown stats (total=0, active=0, idle=0, waiting=0)
10:26:33.528 [main] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
10:26:33.548 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute ApplicationRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:771)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:758)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301)
    at jp.co.abc.english.BatchApplication.main(BatchApplication.java:14)
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE where JOB_NAME = ? and JOB_KEY = ?]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'education.BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE' doesn't exist
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:239)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:70)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1541)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:667)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:713)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:744)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:757)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:815)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobInstanceDao.getJobInstance(JdbcJobInstanceDao.java:151)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.isJobInstanceExists(SimpleJobRepository.java:93)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy77.isJobInstanceExists(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:128)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy77.isJobInstanceExists(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.getNextJobParameters(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:206)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.execute(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:198)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:173)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:160)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.run(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:155)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.run(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:150)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:768)
    ... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'education.BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE' doesn't exist
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1003)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:722)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:651)
    ... 42 common frames omitted
```

Comment: I don't think this is related to the Boot version. You have set `spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema` to `never`. This means you are telling Spring Boot *not* to create tables for you in the target datasource. In that case, you need to create those tables manually before starting your job. According to the error, the table `education.BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE` does not exist. Are you sure you have already created the tables beforehand?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine I don't have those tables from earlier, in previous spring boot version also it was working without that. 
After changing it from spring.batch.initialize-schema: never to spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema: never, I am getting this error.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine I think it is because of my changes in DefaultBatchConfigurer.

Comment: IIIC it was working because you were using the map based job repository. With the new version, you also changed to job repository to be jdbc based by using a datasource. Your are autowiring the datasource by passing it as a parameter in the `batchConfigurer()` bean definition method. This datasource is auto-configured by Boot but not initialized with Batch's tables according to the property `spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema=never`. So you either need to set this property to another value or create tables yourself beforehand in the target datasource.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine "need to set this property to another value" means? I need to set other than "never"? 
What if I don't want to create those tables? 
do we have any other way to resolve this?

Comment: yes, a value other than "never". For example, you can set it to "embedded" and use an embedded datasource (like H2, HSQL, etc) for the batch meta-data. This is the recommended replacement for the deprecated Map-based job repository implementation.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine is there any other way to do not create spring initialize schema?